# Safari web inspector stop working after mac update

Tags: macos, ionic-framework, safari, macos-big-sur

After 24 May (yesterday) mac update for Big Sur (11.4), the web inspector only shows Console, Sources, and Audit tab. The Console tab doesn’t show any from the app, it’s always empty. Source Tab doesn’t show the app code anymore. Tried to clean up Safari Cache, also have tried Safari Technology Preview, and none of this worked, still the same annoying thing. Anyone here has experienced something like it?

Safari Version 14.1.1 (16611.2.7.1.4)

Safari Technology Preview Version Release 124 (Safari 14.2, WebKit 16612.1.11.10)

Env:

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.16
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.11.13
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.803.29
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.1.3
   @angular/cli                  : 8.1.3
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.0.0

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : ios 5.1.1
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.1, (and 21 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res (update available: 0.15.3) : 0.14.0
   native-run (update available: 1.3.0)   : 1.0.0

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 
   ios-sim           : 8.0.2
   NodeJS            : v10.16.3
   npm               : 6.9.0
   OS                : macOS Big Sur
   Xcode             : Xcode 12.5 Build version 12E262
```

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same issue after updating to the latest Safari the other day, which drove me insane today.
Fortunately, after struggling for hours, I found a temporary way that might also solve your problem, which is to download an older version Safari Technology Preview from: https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/56677/safari-technology-preview, which works properly for me now :)

Also I have reported this issue on Feedback Assistant, hope they get it fixed ASAP.

Comment: Thanks man, well I've downgraded macOS from 11.4 to 11.3.1, it was a radical solution but it worked fine.

Comment: Robert, did that actually work for you? When I execute any of the resulting pkg files listed there they claim that I need to have an older version of Mac for the installation to occur.

Comment: @cSn, yes it worked. But it seems that you have already resolved your problem ;)

Comment: @RobertYoew yeah! I end up downloading the version Safari Technology Preview that ended up having the fix already. Hopefully we'll have the fix for Safari itself soon! Couldn't basically install old Safari Technology Preview versions as they were not compatible with my macOS version.

Comment: I found the latest Safari Technology Preview still broken, I revered to 11.3.1 and that works.

Answer (score 1):

Jean Silva, same here! Same Safari Version: `14.1.1 (16611.2.7.1.4)` and same behavior! Also the "Elements" tab is completely gone and console is just not working.

[image]

Comment: The latest Safari Technology Preview (that has been just published), link: https://secure-appldnld.apple.com/STP/071-45899-20210526-3fe7359c-0f20-4850-b6ec-da9b197119c2/SafariTechnologyPreview.dmg (https://developer.apple.com/safari/download/) seems to have this solved as per notes in release notes! (https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/release-notes)

Comment: Good, I had to downgrade my macOS, as I was in a such hurry. That also worked.

Answer (score 1):

This is clearly a bug in Safari in new version `14.1.1 (16611.2.7.1.4)`. But, they have *just* release a fix to this in the "Safari Technology Preview" (https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/) which can be used instead of regular Safari for also doing web inspection + remote debugging.

- Release notes - Release 125: https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/release-notes/
- Download link: https://secure-appldnld.apple.com/STP/071-45899-20210526-3fe7359c-0f20-4850-b6ec-da9b197119c2/SafariTechnologyPreview.dmg